# What is a universal class in perl?

Tags: perl

Please help me.
I am doing an assignment and I couldn't find the answers for this question.I tried many web sites but there no answer in any of them.
What is a universal class in perl?
What is it's use.

Comment: [`perldoc UNIVERSAL`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I shamelessly turned that into an answer. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @simbabque nope, I'll even upvote it :)

Answer (score 5):

If the question is indeed for *a universal class*, then that question is going to be very hard to answer. That implies that there is a concept with that name, and that you can apply that concept to your class. But that is not the case.

There is only *the `UNIVERSAL` class* in Perl. Here, `UNIVERSAL` is the name of *a specific class*. It is the base class for all other classes. [As Hunter McMillan pointed out in their comment on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419225/what-is-a-universal-class-in-perl#comment54627895_33419225), you should read [the perldoc on `UNIVERSAL`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html).